# Why is (3.3==np.asarray([3.3])) equal to [True] instead of False?

Tags: python, unit-testing, numpy, testing

Following statement passes in my tests.

```
self.assertEqual(3.3, np.asarray([3.3]))
```

One type is `numpy.float64` other is `numpy.ndarray` and my assumption was that this test will fail but it passes.

Following statement prints `[ True]`

```
print(3.3 == np.asarray([3.3]))
```

Debugging further shows that `assertEquals` ends up invoking `unittest.case.TestCase#_baseAssertEqual` which checks equality using `==`:

```
if not first == second:
        standardMsg = '%s != %s' % _common_shorten_repr(first, second)
        msg = self._formatMessage(msg, standardMsg)
        raise self.failureException(msg)
```

Can someone explain why and how test `self.assertEqual(3.3, np.asarray([3.3]))` passes?

**Edit:** How `==` works in case you compare an array of one value with a variable and where is this behaviour documented?

Comment: But haven't you already determined why this `assertEqual` passes? As you say, `3.3 == np.asarray([3.3])` evaluates to `[ True]`. So the behavior appears to be: if `a == b` gives a [truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-in-python-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false) value, then `assertEqual(a,b)` will pass.

Comment: you seem to have answered the question yourself, as noted by @Kevin. if you want you can additinaly [check the types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIsInstance) and fail tests, if there is a mismatch

Comment: @Kevin I guess my question should have been that how `==` works in case you compare an array of one value with a variable and where is this behaviour documented?

Comment: @Kevin but that does not explain why a float64 object of value 3.3 equals a ndarray holding a float64 of value 3.3 as the only element,does it?

Comment: Perhaps "Why does `3.3 == np.asarray([3.3])` evaluate to anything other than False?" is an interesting and worthwhile question, in which case I feel it ought to be asked independently of a question centered around assertEquals

Comment: `[True]` is a true value, so of course the test passes. You want to print `not (3.3 == np.asarray([3.3]))` instead!

Comment: @ shmee: perhaps it is less striking that `bool(np.array(True)) is True`? hard to expect `False` here, right?  this is a step in the middle in evaluating `3.3 == np.array([3.3])`

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak So you are saying that because `bool(3.3)` is True and `bool(ndarray(True))` is True, as a consequence `3.3 == ndarray(True)` must be True as well? If so, I disagree :). I guess either numpy's float64 or ndarray implementation do a conversion, either the scalar to ndarray or the ndarray to scalar. Otherwise one could also expect `5 == [5]` to be True, which it cleary is not.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But why is it `[True]` ? One can expect that comparing an array of float to a float will return false given that even types aren't same.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh: because numpy arrays use *broadcasting*. The comparison doesn't apply to the array as a whole, instead you get a new array with the results of the comparison applied to each value in the array. You can then use the boolean array that gives to do further operations.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [numpy docs about ndarrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#arithmetic-matrix-multiplication-and-comparison-operations):

> Arithmetic and comparison operations on ndarrays are defined as
>   element-wise operations, and generally yield ndarray objects as
>   results.

The `==` operation on ndarrays returns another ndarray, not a single boolean `True` or `False`.

This is useful for data processing, but it's different from almost every other python object, is which `A == B` would return a simple boolean.

Answer (score 0):

In `Python` one can add several `__eq__` methods on a specific type, to make it comparable with another. Probably some kind of that is done with `numpy.ndarray`.

In that case when `a == b` is checked then it translates to `a.__eq__(b)`. And if type for `a` has implemented `__eq__` method comparison for `b`'s type they can be compared with `==`.

Source: [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**eq**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__)

Comment: confused about _several_ `__eq__` methods, can you provide an example?